# Github checkins overrides changes when latest is not taken

Tags: git, github, egit, tortoisegit

My team has the repository stored in GitHub. If a file (file1) has been modified by developer1 (in local repo) and committed to remote repository. Now another person (developer2) modifies the same file in his local repo without syncing the latest from remote repo, the changes get committed to remote repo (force pushed). There is no warning from GitHub remote repository or the git client (we use Tortoise Git client or eGit). Please suggest if there is a way to prevent this by making any setting changes in remote repository or the git client.

Probably some settings in git hooks needed?

Comment: Add a file called execute_me.sh to your repository with the following contents: `echo "echo \"Before starting work, visit http://git-scm.com/doc\"" >/etc/bashrc` - to be serious, pulling and merging are basic concepts in decentralized Version control systems like git.

Comment: Edited the question to be more clearer. Is there a way to warn or throw error if a developer has not synced latest from remote repo before pushing the changes to remote repo. Remember git hooks (pre-commit) was used in one of my earlier projects to prevent it but dont recall what exactly was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the changes get committed to remote repo (force pushed)

That only happens when whoever's doing the push goes out of their way to force it.

That's your problem: people deciding to explicitly overwrite work they didn't do.

In Git, you do

```
git config receive.denyNonFastForwards true
git config receive.denyDeletes true
```

(and there's lots more granularity available, see the git config docs) on the receiving end to stop people doing that to a repo.

GitHub doesn't allow direct access to that level of repository administration, they're a front-end.  They call their flavoring "[protected branches](https://help.github.com/articles/about-protected-branches/)".

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE** - Question originally did not specify force push.  This completely changes the answer (though not in a way the asker will likely appreciate); preserving the original answer for reference, because it is still the correct way to coordinate changes.

---

A force push specifically means that the person pushing wants to override the history.  If this wasn't intended, then a force push should not have been used.  Usually this combination of questions means that someone tried to push and, when they got an error that they needed to sync first, thought it sounded easier to force push.

Since force push means "I want to override history", git is not going to respond with a warning that you're about to override history.

You can use `--force-with-lease` instead of `--force`.  This allows you to tell git specifically *what* you expect to override from the history, and git will fail the operation and warn you if the history you're *actually* overriding is different from that (i.e. because someone pushed something you didn't yet know about).

But that "added safety" still isn't enough for force pushes to belong in your day-to-day workflow.  In 99.99999% of all cases, the better solution is to train your developers not to force push and to instead honor the error git gives on a regular push, which tells you exactly what needs to happen to sync your changes with those of your teammates.

---

*Original Answer*:

The premise in your question title is incorrect; the second developers changes do *not* "override" the first developers changes.

The point at which changes are integrated is when syncing between repos with push and fetch (or pull).  Each local repo (clone) is an independent repo in which the user can - and *must be able to* - commit without concern for whether someone else might have committed to the corresponding branch in a different repo.

Since you expect GitHub to warn developer2, I take that to mean that developer1 has committed and pushed their changes.  This is good.  So now developer2 commits some changes, not yet having updated from the remote.  Still ok.  Now *when developer2 tries to push*, an error will result saying that developer2's branch is not up to date.  *That* is how git avoids losing developer1's changes.

So developer2 will be told to fetch and merge (or rebase), or pull, the latest changes before being allowed to push.

The git model is one of distributed development.  It is essential that developers be able to commit independently, and in fact you wouldn't want to be trying to merge changes that haven't been committed because then if something went wrong you could lose those changes.  So merges are always done locally and always among committed changes.

Comment: Edited the question to be more clearer. Is there a way to warn or throw error if a developer has not synced latest from remote repo before pushing the changes to remote repo. Remember git hooks (pre-commit) was used in one of my earlier projects to prevent it but dont recall what exactly was done.

Comment: But in our case the developers are not getting error messages when they are committing. Neither they explicitly say force push while pushing the changes. So is the default setting is to force push? Should they make changes in the config file as @jthill mentioned: "git config receive.denyNonFastForwards true" and
"git config receive.denyDeletes true"

Comment: No, the default is not to force push.  You keep saying you expect an error when they commit; that's not how it works.  The commit operation does not communicate with the remote.  You can configure the origin repo to completely forbid force pushes (the settings you describe) if you want, but there's usually no reason to.